# ListView ViewHolder components returning null Android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I have implemented the ViewHolder pattern for my Listview like so:-

```
    public class HomeListAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {

        public HomeListAdapter(List<Models.MyModel> myList, Activities.HomeActivity homeActivity)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.myList = myList;
            this.homeActivity = homeActivity;
            prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(homeActivity);

            inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(homeActivity);

        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return myList.Count; }
        }
        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }



        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if (position == 0 || position == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View rootView = convertView;
            MyViewHolder mHolder;
            var mData = myList[position];

            int item = GetItemViewType(position);   
            if(rootView ==null)
            {
                mHolder = new MyViewHolder(); ;
                switch(item)
                {
                    case 1:
                        rootView = homeActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.phone_home_big_row2, null);
                        mHolder.txtDate = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDate);
                         mHolder.txtTitle = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);

                         mHolder.txtDetail = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDetail);
                         mHolder.imgPlaceholderImage = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPlaceholderImage);
                         mHolder.txtCategory = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategory);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rootView = homeActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.phone_home_list_row, null);
                        mHolder.txtTitle = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);
                        mHolder.txtDate = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDate);
                        mHolder.viewColor = convertView.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.viewColor);
                        mHolder.imgPlaceholderImage = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPlaceholderImage);
                        break;
                }

                rootView.Tag = mHolder;
            }
            else
            {
                mHolder = (MyViewHolder)rootView.Tag;
            }

           switch(item)
           {
               case 1:
                     mHolder.txtTitle.Text = mData.Title;
            if (mHolder.txtDetail != null)
            {
                mHolder.txtDetail.Text = mData.BodyText;
                mHolder.txtDetail.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
                mHolder.txtDetail.SetMaxLines(3);
                mHolder.txtDetail.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            }
            if (mHolder.txtCategory != null)
            {
                mHolder.txtCategory.Text = mData.NewsSourceTitle;
                mHolder.txtCategory.SetTextColor(Color.White);

                mHolder.txtCategory.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(mData.Color));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mData.PublishedDate))
            {
                mHolder.txtDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(mData.PublishedDate).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

                   break;
               case 2:
                   mHolder.txtTitle.Text = mData.Title;

                   if (mHolder.viewColor != null)
                   {
                       mHolder.viewColor.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(mData.Color));
                   }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mData.PublishedDate))
                   {
                      mHolder.txtDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(mData.PublishedDate).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }


                   break;

           }






            return rootView;
        }
        public class MyViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
        {

            public TextView txtTitle { get; set;}
            public TextView txtDate{ get; set;}
            public TextView txtDetail{ get; set;}
            public ImageView imgPlaceholderImage { get; set; }
            public View viewColor { get; set; }
            public TextView txtCategory { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

But i always mHolder.txtTitle and the other components as null, even if the mHolder is not null.  I need to inflate two different layouts depending upon their positions.Is there something wrong I am doing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In switch case, use rootView.FindViewById instead of convertView.FindViewById.

Comment: Use  "(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);" instead of  "convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDate);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is arising because your code sometimes refers to `rootView` and sometimes to `convertView`.

In this line, you perform `findViewByID()` on `convertView`:

```
mHolder.txtTitle=convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);
```

However, you never checked if `convertView` is null and assigned it a new `View` if it is.  Instead, you created a new reference to `convertView`, which you called `rootView`, check if *that* was null, and if it was, then you assigned a new `View` to *rootView*.  thus, `rootView` now is non-null, but `convertView` still is.

```
public override View GetView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
    View rootView=convertView;
    //...
    if(rootView==null)
    {
      mHolder=new MyViewHolder();;
      switch(item)
      {
        case 1:
          rootView = homeActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.phone_home_big_row2,null);
          mHolder.txtDate=convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDate); 
                        // ^^^^^^^^^^ convertView can still be null!!!
          //...
      }
```

I suggest you remove all references to `rootView` in your code and just work with `convertView` directly.  that's why it's provided to your method.

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. Thanks for detailed answer. This did solve my problem, but now when I scroll down the app crashes with error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2`

Comment: If you have a new problem, post a new question.  One question, one answer.  You can reference this question in your post for background if necessary, but put all the needed information in your new question.  Glad you solved this problem.  And if you are getting a crash, post your code and crash log so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should return items in particular position from the getItem overrided method

```
public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return myList(position);
    }
```